# Publish a hierarchical policy document with comments

Tags: document

I am trying to publish our company policy documents in a hierarchical manner such that:

1. Each section of the policy will expand/collapse with sub-sections
   similar to a treeview.
2. Each section of the policy is a seperate item that can be commented
   on.
3. Each section of the policy can have Tags relative to thier topic
   that can be searched on.

My thought is to create a custom list with columns for document section number, section body, section tags, then somehow create a discussion board for each section.

Any thoughts on how this would be implemented?

~Dustbin

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a discussion board with each section of the policy as a new item. It can have custom columns that you can group each policy and sort it by section number. So when you are done with it you have a multiple group by discussion board, one entry for each section.

> > - Company Policy
> >
> > > > - IT Safety
> > > >
> > > > > > Require all passwords to be 10 characters
> > > > > >
> > > > > > Company computers cannot be shared

Each post can have a discussion and comments, as well as a custom column that you can filter out the sections or clauses that you have agreed upon or rejected, etc.